# How can I have a Lightning component globally on every view?

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

I'd like to have a Lightning component available on every page in my org. Essentially, I'm looking to insert an override stylesheet into that component so I can brand the header area.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing it
1.You can insert it into a page template and use that page template to create your pages.
2.You can altogether create a custom theme template and insert into that and use it throughout your application.